# how to get index or position of listview control

Tags: java, android, listview, drag-and-drop, draggable

Hello guys I am new to android programming. I want to create a puzzle game in which user will sort the html unsorted tags by dragging them on the screen. I am using a listview control to store the unsorted html tags. I have implemented the following library:
https://github.com/terlici/DragNDropList

Now I am trying to get the position or index of the list item after user drop the list item so I can compare the user sorted list items to the actual sorted items.

Here is my code Main.java

```
PuzzleManager pm = new PuzzleManager(this);
pm.insertPuzzle("<html>,</h1>,<h1>,</html>,<body>,</body>", "<html>,<body>,<h1>,</h1>,</body>,</html>");
Cursor cursor = pm.getPuzzle(1);
pm.close();
String s = cursor.getString(1); 
List<String> puzzleList = Arrays.asList(s.split(","));
ArrayList<Map<String, Object>> items = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();

for(int i = 0; i < puzzleList.size(); ++i) {
    HashMap<String, Object> item = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    item.put("puzzle", puzzleList.get(i));
    items.add(item);
}

DragNDropListView list = (DragNDropListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);
DragNDropSimpleAdapter adaptor = new DragNDropSimpleAdapter(this,
        items,
        R.layout.row,
        new String[]{"puzzle"},
        new int[]{R.id.text},
        R.id.handler);
list.setDragNDropAdapter(adaptor);
```

Main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<com.terlici.dragndroplist.DragNDropListView
    android:id="@id/android:list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="80px"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/handler"
        android:layout_width="60px"
        android:layout_height="60px"
        android:src="@android:drawable/btn_star_big_on"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8px"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: "DragNDropListView provides an event listener for drag and drop": *list.setOnItemDragNDropListener(...)*. Use it to get index of the item dropped (the **id**)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
list.setOnItemDragNDropListener(new DragNDropListener(){
                public void onItemDrop(DragNDropListView parent, View view, int startPosition, int endPosition, long id)
                {
                    super.onItemDrop(parent, view, startPosition, endPosition, id);
                    Log.i("long clicked","pos"+" "+endPosition+" id "+id);
                }

        });
```